# jodconverter java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: openoffice.org, jodconverter

I have installed openoffice and jodconverter on ubuntu 12.04 (64) in order to convert .xls into pdf.

I have the same installation on 10.04 (64) working great, however having just built a new machine with freshly installed 12.04, it simply refuses to run.

It is a headless machine and openoffice is called with:

```
soffice --headless --nologo --nofirststartwizard "--accept=socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp"
```

I have confirmed that it is listening on 8100:

```
netstat -an | grep 8100
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8100          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

however runnind jodconverter (to convert pcash.xls to pcash.pdf) always results in this ClassNotFound error:

```
jodconverter pcash.xls pcash.pdf
Oct 4, 2012 3:07:52 PM com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.AbstractOpenOfficeConnection connect
INFO: connected
Oct 4, 2012 3:07:52 PM com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.AbstractOpenOfficeConnection disposing
INFO: disconnected
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/star/task/ErrorCodeIOException
at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.cli.ConvertDocument.main(ConvertDocument.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.star.task.ErrorCodeIOException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

I have clicked pretty much every link in google, I have installed open-office with apt-get as well as by downloading the latest and installing from .deb and it makes no difference.

This works flawlessley on 10.04 and yet I have spent the last 6 hours getting nowhere !!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using openoffice and not libreoffice which is default in ubuntu? 
I have experienced some problems with newer versions of LibreOffice.

Also there might be issues with supporting newer versions of OpenOffice since JODConverter is no longer maintained. Try the same OpenOffice version you had with 10.04